# INSERT query produces "Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I am confused about why I am received the following message:

> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

**This question is different from previous queries** because my query actually **executes correctly** (values were indeed entered into the database). So, I would expect MySQL to return a result set and NOT A BOOLIAN.

**Below is my function:**

```
function join_main_newsletter($firstName = null, $email)
{
    global $dbc;
    $valuesEntered = "values entered";

    $insert = "INSERT INTO newsletter (first_name, email ) VALUES ('name', 'testemail@yahoo.com')";

    $R3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $insert) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: " . mysqli_error(db_conx), E_USER_ERROR);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($R3) == 1) {
        return $valueentered;
    } else {
    }
}
```

**And here is part of the results from the error:**

```
[valuesEntered] => values entered
    [insert] => INSERT INTO newsletter (first_name, email ) 
                  VALUES ('name', 'testemail@yahoo.com')
    [R3] => 1
```

Comment: this is different. my query is working; i.e values are entering into the database. so, i don't have a fault in my query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mysqli_num_rows()` function returns the number of rows in a result set. For insert, update and delete use [`mysqli_affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) - Number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

Comment: *What* may be the reason?

Comment: What should be the result of this? If `mysqli_num_rows()` fails at the first place, because it was an `INSERT`, not a `SELECT`, your code is no help at all.